# Image intervention - replace color

Tags: php, laravel, gd, intervention

I have a small problem. It's been 24hrs and I'm reading through the documentation and can't figure out how or is there even such simple thing as color replace using [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io) package.

In an ideal world, I would have a custom shape filled with one color (#ff00aa) and there would be the ability to change it to another color (#ffffff). Yes, I could use layers and hide color behind, but there's a problem - images are transparent. Let's say I would like to replace the color of cloud or leaves to with different color.

Maybe some of you have faced this or any of you have useful information and want to share with me or could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why don't you use Photoshop, or any image editor?

Comment: @BálintBudavölgyi i am building image generator on php using image intervention. would make no sense having millions pictures with all hex colors :D